# MySQL WorkBench на Mac Big Sur 11.2.2 ошибка сразу при запуске

Tags: mysql, macos, mysql-workbench

Помогите разобраться скачал : https://downloads.mysql.com/archives/workbench/
версия 8.0.22, поставил , запускаешь и сразу ошибка ,переустановка не помогла.

Process:               MySQLWorkbench [1403]
Path:                  /Applications/MySQLWorkbench.app/Contents/MacOS/MySQLWorkbench
Identifier:            com.oracle.workbench.MySQLWorkbench
Version:               8.0.23.CE (1)
Code Type:             X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:        ??? [1]
Responsible:           MySQLWorkbench [1403]
User ID:               501

Date/Time:             2021-03-02 01:52:04.228 +0300
OS Version:            macOS 11.2.2 (20D80)
Report Version:        12

Time Awake Since Boot: 790 seconds
Time Since Wake:       45 seconds

System Integrity Protection: enabled

Crashed Thread:        0  Dispatch queue: com.apple.main-thread

Exception Type:        EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes:       0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Exception Note:        EXC_CORPSE_NOTIFY

Termination Signal:    Abort trap: 6
Termination Reason:    Namespace SIGNAL, Code 0x6

Answer (score 0):

Поставил версию 8.0.21 и все заработало